# Upgraded Linux Kernel 5.15.0.52-lowlatency to 5.15.0.53, it would not boot?

Tags: boot, apt, upgrade, kernel

I upgraded the kernel to 5.15.0-53 and it froze in the middle of the reboot. I sudo rebooted onto the previous kernel 5.15.0-52-lowlatency. I was attempting to remove the upgraded 5.15.0-53 via "apt-get remove" and starting reading what it was fixing to do... add some more 53 and remove some 52 and 50 and suggested I remove unneeded parts of 52 plus nividia modules/signatures... I did not run this because I had concerns. My question is there a way to fix this new kernel upgrade or is it safe to remove it with the "apt-get remove" command? Also could this have anything to do with secure boot being changed for this newer kernel? Further, does this kernel update exceed Ubuntu 22.04 and require that I upgrade Ubuntu 22.04 to use this newer kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem: Kubuntu 22.04 with AMD CPU froze in the middle of reboot with new 5.15.0-53 kernel. While looking for answer, I saw your question.

I can't answer to Your questions, but I'd like you to know, that I found answer to my problem:

I had AMD GPU drivers installed from AMD webpage and after removing them ($ amdgpu-uninstall) the problem was solved.

Works now with secure boot both disabled/enabled in UEFI settings.

While installing kernel to and old Intel CPU computer with exactly the
same OS - no problems at all.

Hope this info helps you or someone else

**EDIT!:**

**I probably can answer your question now:** I think at the moment you have to make a choice between kernel and Nvidia driver (I wrote the same text as comment):

**EITHER** keep Nvidia driver and use previous kernel **OR** get rid of Nvidia driver and use new kernel.

(If you want to play with your computer, after uninstalling Nvidia 470 and rebooting to new kernel, you can re-install Nvidia and see what happens... but every Linux OS includes a GPU driver preinstalled... so you don't NEED to install a separate GPU driver - I probably will never do it again)

Instructions how to do this:

- Here is discussion about compatibility problems with Nvidia 470 driver and kernels and **how to uninstall Nvidia driver**: [how to properly install nvidia 470 drivers on ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370843/how-to-properly-install-nvidia-470-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04)
- Here is **how to downgrade to previous/old kernel**:
  https://www.maketecheasier.com/downgrade-kernel-linux/

Comment: Do you think if I uninstall my nvidia 470 driver and upgrade the kernel that it would update it and update the gpu driver? Could I remove the nvidia 470 driver and do a sudo apt update, sudo apt full upgrade? I am just now putting together that the kernel and the gpu nvidia driver is so closely related.

Comment: I am not a computer expert and don't use nvidia drivers, but the problem in your case could be similar to mine. What I did was boot the computer in previous kernel and remove the AMD GPU drivers. If Nvidia drivers can safely be removed - that is what I would try. Another option is to use the old kernel until Nvidia drivers are updated.

Comment: I think you have to make a choice between kernel and Nvidia drivers: Either keep Nvidia drivers and use previous kernel or get rid of Nvidia drivers and use new kernel

Comment: This did answer my question. I purged the newer kernel image and headers. Will use the older kernel 5.15.0.52 until nvidia is able to provide a "non-free" version that compliments the newer kernel 5.15.0.53. Now I need to figure out a way to stop Ubuntu 22.04 Plasma Discover Updater from updating "linux-objects-nvidia-470-server-5.15.0.53" and "linux-signatures-nvidia...." with the other updates?

Comment: I had made the mistake, that in Discover settings - Software Sources - Updates, I had chosen to download unsupported updates - maybe you have also. In general, Nvidia packages to be updated should be at the list in Discover Settings - page.

Comment: I switched off unsupported updates, however Discover is still showing the unwanted update, so to be safe I used Muon Package Manager that left no doubt. Does this next bit sound correct? *A Nouveau Nvidia driver was compiled to work with the new kernel 5.15.0.53. The Nvidia proprietary driver being used conflicted, plus it has yet to be compiled by Nvidia to work with the new kernel?   Finland :)